# How do I get started on developing Pandora like app on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I am a newbie iOS Developer. Could anybody point me in the right direction how can I develop pandora like app?

However, unlike Pandora, user should be able to view/play from the catalog or use recommendation engine. At this moment, I am not worried about recommendation engine. Basically, I want the app to be able to present sound file collection and play selected mp3 or entire album (play, pause, shuffle, repeat, etc). I want the melody catalog to be easily maintainable. I guess I will not store files locally. They have to be streamed from the server (HTTP Live Streaming?)??? The list will keep getting bigger and I will be the only person adding tracks.

What frameworks/libraries/documentation should I read up on?

Anyways, I learn better by doing it, so even though this is not an easy task, decided to take on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds rather intense for a first project.  You might want to start a bit smaller.  Just store the audio files locally.  Once you get comfortable with that, then look into streaming.  Just my suggestion, and it doesn't help answer your question.

Comment: My suggestion for where to start with playing audio is also with `AVPlayer` as mentioned in the Apple docs, but do yourself a favour and get an almost-complete version already: [`NGMoviePlayer`](https://bitbucket.org/brentsimmons/ngmovieplayer).

Comment: As others have said, this is way too much for someone starting out. It has taken others a significant amount of time to build something like what you've described, so you'll need to break this into more manageable chunks. However, Neil Mix, the primary developer of Pandora's iOS application, came and talked at my class, so you might want to watch the video of his presentation about how this application was built: http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/14-2.-guest-speaker-neil-mix/id407243032?i=89378878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good choice... learning by doing.

What I found useful in getting started with iOS was the online stanford class and the apple documentation concerning Audio:

[Stanford Youtube Course](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oesNwgHn1ws&feature=plcp&context=C3768717UDOEgsToPDskLZnFDDjqzpAdMDu6y9Rplu)

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AudioVideoStartingPoint_iOS/index.html)